Is there a plan to build an atmosphere colony (a "cloud city") on Earth?
I understand that Earth's atmosphere ends at 500 km above sea level; then starts the exosphere/space.
I further understand that the international space station orbits earth at 400 km above sea level.
I was surprised to learn that flying crafts including a large one such as the international space station can orbit Earth (instead of falling into the ground) so relatively close to maneuvering distance of 100,000 feet (about 30.50 km above sea level) for the most advanced army aircraft today, given that some small satellites orbit Earth at about 35,000 km above sea level.
If large complexes such as the international space station can orbit earth "so close" to sea level then I think it shouldn't be very far off to think about "cloud cities" (for lack of a better term) of large modular building complexes with people living in them for years with the option to stay above or come down to earth sometimes.
This concept is similar to the Venus cloud city concept.
Is there a plan to build an atmosphere colony (a "cloud city") on Earth?

Are you sure the ISS is relevant here? The ISS is traveling at roughly Mach 25. No existing conventional airplane can reach even Mach 4, so you couldn't use a conventional plane for transport even if you could somehow get it to the right altitude.

Yes, there is some atmosphere at the iss altitude but it's so tenuous the only notable affect it has is to add some drag so that the station has to regularly be boosted back into a higher orbit. The common definition of the start of space is 100km

Balloons don't go anywhere near this high, current record is under 55km https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_balloon

@AlanBirtles More to the point, 100km (the Karman line) is where it stops being possible to generate aerodynamic lift. While it's not a hard dividing line between atmosphere and space, there is a pretty clear line between where you can fly like an airplane, and where you need to fly like a spacecraft.

@hi_there Welcome to space stack exchange. I think the question has been down voted a little harshly as you're new here. As written today (14-Oct-2024) the question has been answered fairly directly by Gremlin Wrangler's response - i.e "is there a plan" will have either a "yes"/"no"/"maybe" answer so you could simply accept their answer if its helpful to you. If you'd like to see more explanation you could edit this question or raise a new one, though, do engage with the comments already given if you need to get to the bottom of any difficult concepts.

Also, this is a question and answer site rather than a forum, check out the tour https://space.stackexchange.com/tour to get an idea of how it is supposed to work.

This question is not really on topic here. This site is for questions about Space Exploration, not speculative science fiction.

Not as described
Relevant XKCD discussing the fact that the altitude of the ISS is not really relevant here, the speed is. And that speed is only viable above the altitude where 'cloud city' is meaningful.
There have been various proposals for airborne cities but none that have progressed particularly. They suffer from most of the issues that seaborne cities do in terms of lacking a functional economy while being more expensive, and are even more vulnerable to weather issues.
There is some intersection between space stations and terrestrial floating cities since both require compact solutions for growing food.
